# SAP Gui Scripting Looping

Tags: excel, vba, user-interface, sap-gui

I wrote a script that runs IW31 and copy the values from excel to SAP. After first row the scripts does not repeat the loop. I wonder where my mistake is at looping procedure. Thanks for your help!

```
Public SapGuiAuto, WScript, MsgCol
Public ObjGui As GuiApplication
Public ObjCon As GuiConnection
Public Session As GuiSession

Sub WOCreate()

    'Connection to SAP
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
    Set ObjGui = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
    Set ObjCon = ObjGui.Children(0)
    Set Session = ObjCon.Children(0)
    
    ObjGui.AllowSystemMessages = False
    ObjGui.HistoryEnabled = False
    Session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize

    
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim ActRng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set ActRng = Range("A1")
    Set Rng = Sheets("Load").Range("A2")
    Rowmax = Rng.End(xlDown).Row - Rng.Row 'Find no of rows used in the file
    
    Session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/NIW31" 'WO Creation Screen
    Session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    
    
    For i = 1 To Rowmax 'Loop Starts
    
        Session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/NIW31"
        Session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
        Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtAUFPAR-PM_AUFART").Text = ActRng.Offset(i, 0).Value
        Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subOBJECT:SAPLCOIH:7120/ctxtCAUFVD-TPLNR").Text = ActRng.Offset(i, 1).Value
        Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRC62C-REFNR").Text = ActRng.Offset(i, 2).Value
        Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/chkRC62C-FOLLOW_UP_ORDER").Selected = True
        Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/chkRC62C-COPY_OPR").Selected = True
        Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/chkRC62C-COPY_MAT").Selected = True
        Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/chkRC62C-FOLLOW_UP_ORDER").SetFocus
        Session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
        Session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
        Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cmbCAUFVD-PRIOK").Key = "3"
        Session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
        Session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
        Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_ALL:SAPLCOIH:3001/ssubSUB_LEVEL:SAPLCOIH:1100/subSUB_KOPF:SAPLCOIH:1102/subSUB_TEXT:SAPLCOIH:1103/cntlLTEXT/shell").Text = ActRng.Offset(i, 3) + vbCr + "" + vbCr + ""
        Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_ALL:SAPLCOIH:3001/ssubSUB_LEVEL:SAPLCOIH:1100/subSUB_KOPF:SAPLCOIH:1102/subSUB_TEXT:SAPLCOIH:1103/cntlLTEXT/shell").SetSelectionIndexes 28, 28
        Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_ALL:SAPLCOIH:3001/ssubSUB_LEVEL:SAPLCOIH:1100/tabsTS_1100/tabpIHKZ/ssubSUB_AUFTRAG:SAPLCOIH:1120/subHEADER:SAPLCOIH:0154/ctxtCAUFVD-INGPR").Text = ActRng.Offset(i, 4).Value
        Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_ALL:SAPLCOIH:3001/ssubSUB_LEVEL:SAPLCOIH:1100/tabsTS_1100/tabpIHKZ/ssubSUB_AUFTRAG:SAPLCOIH:1120/subHEADER:SAPLCOIH:0154/ctxtCAUFVD-VAPLZ").Text = ActRng.Offset(i, 5).Value
        Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_ALL:SAPLCOIH:3001/ssubSUB_LEVEL:SAPLCOIH:1100/tabsTS_1100/tabpIHKZ/ssubSUB_AUFTRAG:SAPLCOIH:1120/subHEADER:SAPLCOIH:0154/ctxtCAUFVD-ILART").Text = ActRng.Offset(i, 6).Value
        Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_ALL:SAPLCOIH:3001/ssubSUB_LEVEL:SAPLCOIH:1100/tabsTS_1100/tabpIHKZ/ssubSUB_AUFTRAG:SAPLCOIH:1120/subTERM:SAPLCOIH:7300/ctxtCAUFVD-REVNR").Text = ActRng.Offset(i, 7).Value
        Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_ALL:SAPLCOIH:3001/ssubSUB_LEVEL:SAPLCOIH:1100/tabsTS_1100/tabpIHKZ/ssubSUB_AUFTRAG:SAPLCOIH:1120/subTERM:SAPLCOIH:7300/ctxtCAUFVD-REVNR").SetFocus
        Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_ALL:SAPLCOIH:3001/ssubSUB_LEVEL:SAPLCOIH:1100/tabsTS_1100/tabpIHKZ/ssubSUB_AUFTRAG:SAPLCOIH:1120/subTERM:SAPLCOIH:7300/ctxtCAUFVD-REVNR").CaretPosition = 7
        Session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press
        Session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
       
        ActRng.Offset(i, 8).Value = Session.findById("wnd[0]/sbar").Text 'Status Message
       
    Next i
        
    MsgBox "Process Completed"
    
    
End Sub
```

Comment: First - what is the value of Rowmax? Is it mote then 1? Second - I don't have transaction NIW31 access in SAP, but i've been working with SAP automation a bit. Are you sure that loop returns SAP to the GUI window before loop? You enter transaction inside a loop - but does the code exit transaction after every loop?

Comment: Debug your code to know the value of `Rowmax`. Probably it's not what you expect.

Comment: Gentlemans, thanks for the help and comments. I have checked my code based on your comments and I noticed that my range was not correct. Also, I moved tcode out of loop. The only problem I faced right now my code stops at this line:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code with a sample data and is working for me.

The problem may be within the Rowmax variable.

You could try updating it to this and see if it works:

`Rowmax = Sheets("Load").Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, Rng.Column).End(xlUp).Row 'Find no of rows used in the file`

Comment: Here is the debug line of my code Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subOBJECT:SAPLCOIH:7100/ctxtCAUFVD-TPLNR").Text = objSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value